How would you describe the difference between "each" and "everyone" to an English newbie?
Correct me if I'm wrong, my explanation would be, "each" needs to refer to a noun mentioned in the same sentence whereas "everyone" doesn't.
For example:

Each person at the party looked happy.
Everyone at the party looked happy.
He fired three shots, each with the utmost precision.


Explicit mention of a noun is not required. Compare the saying "To each his own".

Are you asking about the differences in grammar rules, or in meaning?

@gotube about both

@TimR You're right, but isn't that an exception?

It's not an exception but a generalization. Compare: "All should have access to health care" or "Each should do as they see fit."

You can address a group with everyone: "Everyone, can I have your attention for a minute."  To do something similar with each would be "Each of you, can I have your attention..."

'Each' emphasises the individuality of the members the group.
For example, "everybody met him" might describe a situation where a group was collectively introduced to someone, whereas "each one met him" could mean they were all introduced one by one.
When they are used together, eg "each and every one of you" it can just be a figure of speech for emphasis, but it ought to mean that what is being said applies to the group as well as to the individuals. For example, "best wishes to each and ever one of you" means that well-wishes are not only for the group collectively, but for the individuals. A comparable alternative is "one and all".

Also, each can serve in a pronoun-like way in a manner that every can’t. As an example, “Julia, Eleanor, and Rose met for lunch. Each offered to pick up the tab.” By contrast, every by itself can never serve as the subject of verbs, object of prepositions, etc.

@PaulTanenbaum I actually meant the difference between "each" and "everyone", not the one between "each" and "every".

As to the pair each and everyone,  to address what your title asks, I would say that there is no single well-defined difference between them. To address your hypothesis that when each is used pronominally it must have an antecedent in the same sentence, I would say, “To each, his own.”

@siegmundfreud I've added some detail about both being used together, hope that covers it

@Paul Tanenbaum does "each at the party looked happy" sound natural to you, though?

No, freestanding each (or maybe better said, pronominal each?) doesn’t generally tolerate modifications other than prepositional phrases with of.

@PaulTanenbaum What do you mean by "modification" in this case? Also, can you rephrase it in a more simple way? I find that people on this forum tend to sometimes speak too complex and it gives me a headache trying to decipher and Google what they said.

What I meant here by modifications is things like your at the party, which serves to restrict the meaning of—and thus modify—each. That sounds clumsy and wrong to native speakers. If it read instead, “Each guest at the party looked happy,” that would be fine. But in that case, each would be a determiner, and not acting like a pronoun. And the prepositional phrase at the party would be modifying guest, not each.
